# Cross device h264 compatible html5 video

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, h.264

I'm trying to serve a large video of timelapses generated from a series of images. 
Using FFmpeg I have encoded the video as an h264 mp4.

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i "/app/download/%d.jpeg" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset fast -tune animation -report -vf "format=yuv420p" -y /app/output.mp4
```

I'm running into compatibility issues where the videos are not playable on iOS (safari) as well as on Windows (all browsers except chrome). Where I'm getting the following error:

`Error Code: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_FATAL_ERR (0x806e0005) Details: mozilla::MediaResult __cdecl mozilla::WMFVideoMFTManager::ValidateVideoInfo(void): Can't decode H.264 stream because its resolution is out of the maximum limitation`

See the full FFmpeg log here: https://pastebin.com/QUEPh3q2

I'm just looking for some resource or knowledge of how to encode my media for maximum compatibility while still preserving high quality and resolution.

**Problem:**
Which options I should be using in FFmpeg to maximize compatibility?

Comment: Add -report and rerun to generate log and share that.

Comment: Is your video resolution larger than the supported width x height of `8192 x 4320` pixels? Are you using a specific / special hardware to showcase the large video (_eg:_ some exhibition computer with latest GPU hardware etc)? I ask because if this is just for website visitors then also remember not everyone's device or net connection can handle 8K+ sized videos.

Comment: @Gyan https://pastebin.com/QUEPh3q2 i was not able to attach the full report so i've uploaded it here

Comment: @VC.One my videos are maximally of size 4056 × 3040 or 3040x4056 .
It is for a product I'm building, so it is not generally available. I do expect certain modern computers. I was just hoping that i could maximize compatibility

Answer (score 3):

From comments: *"My videos are maximally of size **4056x3040** or **3040x4056**"*.

I don't have Apple device(s) but you might be hitting some image size limitation on Windows.
Firefox uses the [built-in Windows H264 decoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/h-264-video-decoder?redirectedfrom=MSDN#format-constraints) where the maximum height is `2304`.

Replace the old command:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i "/app/download/%d.jpeg" -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset fast -tune animation -report -vf "format=yuv420p" -y /app/output.mp4
```

With this new one:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i "/app/download/%d.jpeg" -vf scale=3069:2300,setsar=1:1 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v high -crf 23 -preset fast -movflags +faststart -report -y /app/output.mp4
```

The above command changes the size to **3069x2300** (within Windows resolution limits) but I recommend a smaller size like **1441x1080** for maximum device / O.S / browser compatibility.

I would leave out `-tune animation`, add it back if its removal affects your specific image quality.

Now added is `+faststart` which allows the MP4 header to be at front of file (usually is placed last at back) meaning playback can begin without first downloading all videos just to reach header data (which has the decoder settings needed to begin playback).

Answer (score 0):

I think your bigger issue will be trying to send 4056x3040 video over mobile networks.  You're going to have lots of stalling and poor playback over many types of connections that cannot support the bandwidth you'll need. Nor does a mobile device have a big enough screen to actually playback the video dimensions you would be sending.

I'd suggest you look at HLS streaming - and adaptive bitrates.  That way, you can create your huge version, a 1080p version, a 720p version (etc.) the video player will deliver the correctly sized video to the device - no wasted data/pixels, fewer stalls, and it still looks great.